# Rewrite rule issue - capture unique identifier

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to apply logic where i have to capture unique identifier passed to the URL

http://abzc.com/1235a  -> http://abzc.com/content/abc.htm/1235a.htm

The logic that i applied is as below and it works fine-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.htm)
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})$               /content/abc.htm/$1.htm [R=301,L]
```

there could be situation where a user navigates to 
http://abzc.com/content/ars.htm/1235a after the initial landing page so i would need to append .htm again to this URL

tried below logic but it fails totally -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/*.html/(.*)$
RewriteRule .html/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})$ /.html? [L,R=301]
```

Also I need to achieve

http://abzc.com -> http://xayz.com  (i.e. no unique id passed as paramater to abzc.com)

but not sure how to capture if say $1 is null or something like that to handle this one.

Your help is appreciated!